# Options for retrieving Mac crash reports for my application (from customer machines)

Tags: macos, crash, report

I am writing an application for Mac OS X ( >= 10.8). This is not an AppStore app. I would like to make the process of submitting crash reports as easy as possible for my customers. I have found lots of threads on this but most are pretty old and so I would like to recheck the state of this.

1) Is it still true that CrashReporter does not allow overriding the
   upload path for the crash?

2) Is it still true that third-parties
   don't have access to the crash reports for their own apps when those
   reports are uploaded to Apple?

3) Can I get CrashReporter to build
   the crash report without showing a UI? This no-UI restriction would
   have to be applied only to my App ... I don't want to change global
   settings. I would need to do this from my applications code (can't
   ask customer to change some conf file). Then I could possibly let the
   reporter generate the file and then popup my UI (either immediately
   or next time my app is launched perhaps)

4) Can I get CrashReporter
   to show my UI instead of the built in one? Seems unlikely, but I
   thought I would ask.

5) Can I use the code which generates the crash
   report in CrashReporter as a lib that I link to and run in my own
   application? I don't mind their report format and since I assume
   their library will always work across OS versions, seems like this
   would be nice.

6) What are other third-party apps using? I saw
   references to BreakPad, but I am a bit nervous about this running in
   process. I saw a couple of other libs but none seem to have any
   activity for years so that made me nervous.